# Lucene search query using a IntField not working after document update

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to run a simple query on a set of two documents in Lucene using their id and the value of an `Intfield`. The query correctly returns both fields right after adding them. 
Now I use the retrieved document and make a change to the `CONTEXT_FIELD` (which is not used in the query) and update the document in the index.

Interestingly, now the search does not return any results, neither the old nor the new document. If I only use the `METHOD_NAME` field in the query, everything works as expected, the problems seems to be the `NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS` `IntField`.

*Why is this happening?*

Sample Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.IntField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause.Occur;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.NumericRangeQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class LuceneDemo {

private static final String ID1 = "Great#text";
private static final String ID2 = "Another#bonus";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME_FIELD = "method_name";
    private static final String NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS = "number_of_arguments";
    private static final String CONTEXT_FIELD = "context";

    /** Parser used to parse queries */
    private static QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43,
            METHOD_NAME_FIELD, createDefaultAnalyzer());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        IndexWriter luceneIndexWriter = new IndexWriter(
                FSDirectory.open(new File("/tmp/test")), createWriterConfig(64));
        Document doc1 = createDocument(ID1, "context1", 1);
        luceneIndexWriter.addDocument(doc1);
        Document doc2 = createDocument(ID2, "context2", 2);
        luceneIndexWriter.addDocument(doc2);

        System.out.println("Found doc1: "
                + findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter));
        System.out.println("Found doc2: "
                + findDocument(ID2, 2, luceneIndexWriter));
        doc1 = findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter);

        // Section 1
        doc1.removeField(CONTEXT_FIELD);
        doc1.add(new TextField(CONTEXT_FIELD, "context1_changed",
                Field.Store.YES));
        luceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(new Term(METHOD_NAME_FIELD, "text"),
                doc1);

        System.out.println("Found doc1: "
                + findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter));
        System.out.println("Found doc2: "
                + findDocument(ID2, 2, luceneIndexWriter));

        // Section 2
        // doc1 = findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter); <- null
        doc1.removeField(CONTEXT_FIELD);
        doc1.add(new TextField(CONTEXT_FIELD, "context1_changed2",
                Field.Store.YES));
        luceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(new Term(METHOD_NAME_FIELD, "text"),
                doc1);

        System.out.println("Found doc1: "
                + findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter));
        System.out.println("Found doc2: "
                + findDocument(ID2, 2, luceneIndexWriter));

        luceneIndexWriter.close();
    }

    private static Document createDocument(String id, String context, int value) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField(METHOD_NAME_FIELD, id, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField(CONTEXT_FIELD, context, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new IntField(NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS, value, Field.Store.YES));
        return doc;
    }

    private static Document findDocument(String id, int value,
            IndexWriter luceneIndexWriter) throws IOException, ParseException {
        DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(luceneIndexWriter, true);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        String[] split = id.split("#");
        Query methodQuery = parser.parse(split[1]);
        Query classQuery = parser.parse(split[0]);
        NumericRangeQuery<Integer> range = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(
                NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS, 1, value, value, true, true);
        BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
        query.add(methodQuery, Occur.MUST);
        query.add(classQuery, Occur.MUST);
        query.add(range, Occur.MUST);
        TopDocs result = searcher.search(query, 1);
        if (result.totalHits == 0) {
            System.err.println("Problem, nothing found (Method: " + id + ")");
            return null;
        }
        Document document = searcher.doc(result.scoreDocs[0].doc);
        if (document.get(METHOD_NAME_FIELD).equals(id)) {
            return document;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /** create the analyzer used */
    private static Analyzer createDefaultAnalyzer() {
        Map<String, Analyzer> analyzerPerField = new HashMap<String, Analyzer>();
        analyzerPerField.put(NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS, new KeywordAnalyzer());
        PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper analyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(
                new SimpleAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43), analyzerPerField);
        return analyzer;
    }

    /** Creates the configuration used for writing. */
    public static IndexWriterConfig createWriterConfig(double ramBufferSizeMB) {
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43,
                createDefaultAnalyzer());
        config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(ramBufferSizeMB);
        config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        config.setMaxBufferedDeleteTerms(1); // desperate try at
        config.setMaxBufferedDocs(2); // storing everything correctly right away
        // config.setInfoStream(System.out); <- set this for more output
        return config;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found doc1: Document<stored,indexed,tokenized<method_name:Great#text> stored,indexed,tokenized<context:context1> stored<number_of_arguments:1>>
Found doc2: Document<stored,indexed,tokenized<method_name:Another#bonus> stored,indexed,tokenized<context:context2> stored<number_of_arguments:2>>
Problem, nothing found (Method: Great#text)
Found doc1: null
Found doc2: Document<stored,indexed,tokenized<method_name:Another#bonus> stored,indexed,tokenized<context:context2> stored<number_of_arguments:2>>
Problem, nothing found (Method: Great#text)
Found doc1: null
Found doc2: Document<stored,indexed,tokenized<method_name:Another#bonus> stored,indexed,tokenized<context:context2> stored<number_of_arguments:2>>
```

Output including config.setInfoStream(System.out):

http://bpaste.net/show/ko8kkxeFxZFE26NuecZc/ (Too long for inclusion here, sorry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you index the `NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS` field as an `IntField`, but the version passed back from the index is a `StoredField`.  When you reindex it, it is no longer formatted as an `IntField`, and so a `NumericRangeQuery` doesn't get any results.  You can simply set the query term on `NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS` to an `Occur.SHOULD` clause, to see that the problem is on that field.

One solution would be to manually re-add that field to the document, something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    IndexWriter luceneIndexWriter = new IndexWriter(
            FSDirectory.open(new File("/tmp/test")), createWriterConfig(64));
    Document doc1 = createDocument(ID1, "context1", 1);
    luceneIndexWriter.addDocument(doc1);
    Document doc2 = createDocument(ID2, "context2", 2);
    luceneIndexWriter.addDocument(doc2);

    System.out.println("Found doc1: "
            + findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter));
    System.out.println("Found doc2: "
            + findDocument(ID2, 2, luceneIndexWriter));
    doc1 = findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter);

    // Section 1
    doc1.removeField(CONTEXT_FIELD);
    doc1.add(new TextField(CONTEXT_FIELD, "context1_changed",
            Field.Store.YES));

    //re-adding the IntField here
    Number num = doc1.getField(NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS).numericValue();
    doc1.removeField(NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS);
    doc1.add(new IntField(NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS, num.intValue(),
            Field.Store.YES));

    luceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(new Term(METHOD_NAME_FIELD, "text"),
            doc1);

    System.out.println("Found doc1: "
            + findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter));
    System.out.println("Found doc2: "
            + findDocument(ID2, 2, luceneIndexWriter));

    // Section 2
    doc1 = findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter);
    doc1.removeField(CONTEXT_FIELD);
    doc1.add(new TextField(CONTEXT_FIELD, "context1_changed2",
            Field.Store.YES));
    luceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(new Term(METHOD_NAME_FIELD, "text"),
            doc1);
    num = doc1.getField(NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS).numericValue();
    doc1.removeField(NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS);
    doc1.add(new IntField(NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS, num.intValue(),
            Field.Store.YES));
    luceneIndexWriter.updateDocument(new Term(METHOD_NAME_FIELD, "text"),
            doc1);

    System.out.println("Found doc1: "
            + findDocument(ID1, 1, luceneIndexWriter));
    System.out.println("Found doc2: "
            + findDocument(ID2, 2, luceneIndexWriter));

    luceneIndexWriter.close();
}
```

The safer approach is to build a new replacement document, rather than attempting to modify and persist the one pulled from the index.  The stored version of the document retrieved from the index could certainly be lacking a number of pieces of information about how the field should be indexed.

---

One sidenote, when creating a test function that builds a small index, I would use:

```
config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
```

rather than `CREATE_OR_APPEND`.  This allows you to start with an empty index, so results are more readily predictable, and you can view the contents of the index as you build it fresh each time, for debugging, like:

```
public static void outputTheWholeThing(IndexWriter writer) throws IOException {
    DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(writer, true);
    for (int i=0; i<reader.maxDoc(); i++) {
        Document doc = reader.document(i);
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
    System.out.println("Pending deletions:" + reader.numDeletedDocs());
}
```